# How do I establish communication between multiple applications across languages

Tags: c++, sockets, vb6, synchronization, communication

I currently have two programs running that are related to the same operation. Program A (written in vb6) is a sort of "controller" that turns a device on and launches Program B (written in C++) that starts a collection of the device's data. Now, Program B needs a way to report back a few MINOR pieces of the data back to Program A. Program A also needs to monitor certain extra's, and if signal 1 fires, it needs to let Program B know. What is the best way to establish this communication? The obvious ways are a text/binary file that each program reads and writes to (no where near the best way), and I also thought of using UDP to communicate since the machine will be on a closed network. However, I'm unsure of how I should actually do this?

Comment: The best way would be some database (choose depending on the requirements) with defined syntax (SQL) to access the data.

Comment: But how to trigger and synchronize using a DB?  Most don't provide any sort of async notification of updates, forcing you to to do some nasty polling in your programs.

Comment: I agree with Bob here. A DB would not be good for the communication requirements, and probably way over kill since the communication needed is basic signaling.

Answer (score 2):

Named Pipes is an elegant solution, but you can even use files for this as you said.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177696

[How to work with named pipes (C++ server , C# client)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676343/how-to-work-with-named-pipes-c-server-c-sharp-client)

Comment: Looking into this. Will mark if I end up determining this as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are other choices:
Clipboard, COM, Data Copy, DDE, File Mapping, Mailslots, Pipes, RPC, Windows Sockets

Refer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You can also use MSMQ.  Private machine queues are easy to create, destroy, and use.

Comment: whatever you choose, make sure that the resource is released if the program crashes/ends. I know for sure that named pipe is definitely released upon crash.

Comment: If program A runs program B then anonymous pipes can also be used.  The big problem with pipes of either sort, Malslots, etc. is a lack of a clean async implementation for VB6 programs.  This means busy-wait loops or Timer driven polling, which works but isn't so elegant.

Answer (score 0):

how are you turning on the device, and starting Program B?

I would use the same channel for the extra communication, as this line is already there and working (as Program B has started)

Comment: Program A simply shells off Program B. There is no line of communication currently established.

Comment: ah, since program A starts a device i thought program B was running on that device ... if it's a simple shell then all channels might work :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would choose to establish communication and transmit the data using standard protocols for the task, like FTP or HTTP. This way, when your Program A or Program B change (or the medium of connection is swapped out for another), you can still have a well-defined and easy to implement communication protocol. Network stacks are available for a variety of CPUs and operating systems and FTP (or TFTP) are easy to implement.

Comment: I don't see how either of these would work.  Both programs need to send messages and have the other one be notified.  At best both programs would have to implement both a client and a server since these are "one way" protocols.

Comment: HTTP is probably overkill for this problem. TFTP could be a good choice and is trivial to implement, as the name implies. Or perhaps use TFTP to download a large payload of data from the device and a separate, custom protocol over UDP for simple signalling.

Comment: I'm not transferring files between programs, and both programs are on the same PC, so I feel TFTP and HTTP are both heavy overkill, as I'd be sending at MOST probably 50 characters. Thanks for the ideas though

Comment: Oh. You said you had another device to run the program on. In this case yes, a pipe/socket should do.